# Finding and returning the rows of a Pandas dataframe where there is at least one np.inf value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that has some np.inf values and I would like to isolate these rows where the np.inf appears and inspect them.  However the dataframe has many columns and is not easy to examine one by one, although this could be done inside a loop.

I tried this but failed:

```
rows_with_inf = [df1[column][df1[column] == np.inf] for column in df1.columns if ((df1[column].isin([np.inf])).sum() !=0)]

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-94-768652e951ec> in <module>
----> 1 rows_with_inf = [df1[column][df1[column] == np.inf] for column in df1.columns if ((df1[column].isin([np.inf])).sum() !=0)]

<ipython-input-94-768652e951ec> in <listcomp>(.0)
----> 1 rows_with_inf = [df1[column][df1[column] == np.inf] for column in df1.columns if ((df1[column].isin([np.inf])).sum() !=0)]

~\Anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __nonzero__(self)
   1553             "The truth value of a {0} is ambiguous. "
   1554             "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().".format(
-> 1555                 self.__class__.__name__
   1556             )
   1557         )

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

What would be a compact ('pythonic') way to achieve this objective?

Comment: There is no need to add `Your advice will be appreciated` to the footer of all of your questions. You've probably had ~100 removed by now. Remember that the editors that try to keep this place tidy are volunteers. We may be foolish for taking on the task, but we believe in this community, for all its many faults. We would rather not have to clean up after users who add redundant and conversational material wilfully.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) for test at least one `np.inf` per rows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'A':list('abcdef'),
         'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
         'C':[7,8,9,4,np.inf,3],
         'D':[1,np.inf,5,7,1,0],
         'E':[5,3,6,9,2,np.inf],
         'F':list('aaabbb')
})



df1 = df[(df == np.inf).any(axis=1)]
print (df1)
   A  B    C    D    E  F
1  b  5  8.0  inf  3.0  a
4  e  5  inf  1.0  2.0  b
5  f  4  3.0  0.0  inf  b
```

Or if need filter columns and also rows:

```
m = (df == np.inf)
df2 = df.loc[m.any(axis=1), m.any(axis=0)]
print (df2)

     C    D    E
1  8.0  inf  3.0
4  inf  1.0  2.0
5  3.0  0.0  inf
```

**Details**:

```
print (df == np.inf)
       A      B      C      D      E      F
0  False  False  False  False  False  False
1  False  False  False   True  False  False
2  False  False  False  False  False  False
3  False  False  False  False  False  False
4  False  False   True  False  False  False
5  False  False  False  False   True  False

print ((df == np.inf).any(axis=1))
0    False
1     True
2    False
3    False
4     True
5     True
dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check if any value is inf for each row.

```
rows_with_inf = df1[df1.apply(lambda x: any(np.isinf(x)), axis=1)]
```